# Is the flat band of zigzag ribbon topological or just a state of topological origin?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

In my understanding, an edge state has topological origin if its existence is bound to a nontrivial topological invariant. An edge state is topological if it has topological origin.

The flat bands of zigzag ribbon graphene can be related to nontrivial values of Zak phase. In that sense, the edge state should be called topological.
However, it seems these flat bands are not considered as topological by some others.

Furthermore, the flat bands are shown not robust to weak disorders in [PRB 88 205414 (2013)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.205414), which is different from other widely accepted topological edge states, e.g. the edge states of Chern insulators.

Thus, I am wondering the widely accepted definitions of a **topological** edge state and an edge state with **topological origin** and their difference ?